# equals and hashCode defined, arrayList methods still not working

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, hashcode

I've been trying to implement the equals and hashCode method, so I would be able to use the remove method of arrayList.

When i execute the following

```
    Node a = new Node(new Coord(0,0));
    System.out.println(a.equals(nodes.get(0)));
    System.out.println(nodes.get(0).equals(a));
    System.out.println(a.hashCode() == nodes.get(0).hashCode());
    System.out.println(nodes.remove(a));
```

I get the following output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

The question is, how can the first 3 of the output return true when the 4th returns false. The method remove should encounter nodes.get(0) and compare it to a.

These are my equals and hashCode methods:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return coord.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Node node) {
    return (node != null) && (this.hashCode() == node.hashCode());
}
```

which calls the method coord.hashCode() which is defined as:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 23;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: There is a story, no question.

Comment: And include your "nodes" declaration.

Comment: You can use @Override (>= JDK5), in order to ensure that your defined method does not simply overload a parent one, but truly overrides it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current `equals()` method **does not** override `Object.equals()`, it *overloads* it.

Change `equals()` to accept an `Object` parameter:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Node) && (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode());
}
```

Java has the [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation that you can put on methods so the compiler will tell you if your method does not in fact override. It's good practice to use it, so you avoid problems like this at *compile* time.

---

Note that your equals implementation has a bug: You should not compare hash codes - two "unequal" objects may (unluckily) share the same hash code.

Compare fields, not the hash code.

Comment: Or add the (recommended) @Override annotation to your actual method implementation - which reveals the cause of your problem immediately...

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare equals using the method hashCode why:

a.equals(b) == true, a.hashCode() is mandatorily == b.hashCode()

a.hashCode() == b.hashCode(), a.equals(b) NOT is mandatory, more can be == false

Example of implementation using one attribute (x). Generate by eclipse:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + x;
    return result;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (x != other.x)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```